# Kafka consuming offset from compacted topic issue

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka in order to save logs and rebuild the system in case of a crash.

The problem is when a topic is compacted consumer doesn't start from offset 0.

I tried changing consumer_group_ID and resetting offset.

Answer (score 0):

If your topic has had a newer event with the same key as offset 0, then offset 0 will get compacted and is no longer available.

The consumer will instead start at the earliest offset of the first *uniquely keyed* record